Adjust embedded page height based on its content without changing the parent page setting
I am trying to embed my webpage (let's say it is like: https://juacrg.github.io/) in a different webpage (like: https://www.juniv.edu/research/10905). Having no administrative access to this parent site like changing or adding scripts, I can just add a post via the text (visual/html) editor in the page that seems to appear in the container of <p class="card-text"> ... </p>.
I like to embed my webpage such that it is properly adjusted fully by its content without showing a scroll bar in the embedded content and in a way that won't require me to go back and edit in the parent page's container. I was checking the answers here (Adjust width and height of iframe to fit with content in it), and mostly I am getting methods that require changing the parent page settings.
For now, I am trying with iframe in the following way:
<iframe src="https://juacrg.github.io/" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="display: block; width:100%; min-height:3200px; border:none; overflow-y:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;"></iframe>

It looks ok for now, but it is not flexible because I fixed the min-height here. So, it would look odd when the embedded content is reduced. In that case, I have to change the height of this iframe every time, which I won't prefer doing. Also, it is noted that my content has collapsible sections like the ones in https://juacrg.github.io/. I don't prefer getting the iframe scroll bar when the collapsible section is unfolded. Basically, I like to make it view as native content. Is it possible? What can I do? Is there any better way than using iframe?

But if it is still completely impossible without adding scripting to the parent page, what would be the solution with a minimal effective script in this specific scenario with such a parent page structure?

If you have no access then how you are gonna embed it?

I updated the question and I tried to clarify what I meant. I can just create a post in its editor.

If you can not add any scripting to the parent page, then this is simply not possible in a cross-origin scenario.

If you can add a script to the parent, then have a look at https://iframe-resizer.com.
